# How django save method works? Sometimes it creates new record and sometimes update, why?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to ask why this code:

```
object(group_id=group_id, sr=11).save()
```

updates all records with particular group_id and set its sr to 11, whereas the following code creates a new record in the database instead of updating existing records.

```
g = object(group_id=group_id, sr=11)
g.save()
```

The code above creates new record in the database whereas the first code update existing records, why? What is the difference?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If the object’s primary key attribute is set to a value that
  evaluates to True (i.e., a value other than None or the empty
  string), Django executes an **UPDATE**.
- If the object’s primary key attribute is not set or if the UPDATE
  didn’t update anything, Django executes an **INSERT**.

For more details check the Django documentation. [How django knows when to update vs insert](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert)

Comment: if you check snippets in the question, please can you tell me what is the difference between the two snippets? Why one of them has a pk and another has not got?

Answer (score 1):

@chintan Joshi's answer is correct.

Both the code snippets outcome are same if **group_id**  is a primary key.
It will differ if it's not.

Comment: the outcome is not the same, because group_id is not primary key. It is just a field. Also sr is not primary key.

Comment: Exactly, that is what I was trying to explain.
If group_id is primary key then both the code outcome is same.In your case group_id is not the primary key.It will create the new record every time you call save() for info [how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#how-django-knows-to-update-vs-insert)

Answer (score 0):

So finally I found the issue. We can consider Chintan Joshi answer to be correct. The problem was in my code. Because of the database is much older than our project we do not use migrations. We manually map it according to db model. By accident we marked group_id to be primary_key in django models, however in the database it is just a common field. It caused unexpected behavior without warning. Thanks for your answers people.